# Chrome CSS 3 Transition Not Smooth

Tags: html, wordpress, css, google-chrome, responsive-design

Hi working on a site design for a new site and the homepage has some flyup menus using CSS3 transitions.

If you go to --------- and take a look at the "Some Menu that is nice", "Another Cool Menu", etc. links on the homepage in chrome, when you mouse over them the flyups appear but the transition is not smooth and the menu label appears like it is vibrating up and down. I included the CSS below but it is available in the style.css file on the site (relevant parts start on line 1905)

This is only in chrome, Safari and Firefox work fine and IE... well lets not talk about that right now....

```
.home #site-navigation .menu-main-menu-container .trait-box { 
    width: 100%; 
}

.home .main-navigation ul,
.home .main-navigation {
    margin: none;
    border: none;
}

.home .main-navigation ul li {
    border: none;
}

.home .main-navigation ul li a {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.home .trait-box { 
    margin-top: 480px; 
    display: block; 
    text-align: center; 
    height: 126px; 
    position: relative; 
    color: #4e4e4d; 
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.home .trait-box h4 { 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 35px; 
    width: 90%; 
    font-size: 16px;
    font-size: 1.14285714rem;
    line-height: 20px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    font-family: 'ProximaNovaSemibold', Arial, Helvetica;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #D06F4A;
    margin-left: 5%;
}

.home .trait-box figure { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
.home .trait-box figure img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
.home .trait-box dl {
    border-top-color: #D06F4A;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}

.home .trait-box.main-menu-orange dl {
    border-top-color: #D06F4A;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 12px;
}
.home .trait-box.main-menu-teal dl {
    border-top-color: #405C69;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 12px;
}
.home .trait-box.main-menu-blue dl {
    border-top-color: #5E7599;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 12px;
}
.home .trait-box.main-menu-green dl {
    border-top-color: #A9B800;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: 12px;
}

.home .trait-box dd { 
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.07142857rem;
    line-height: 19px;
    line-height: 1.266666667;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    font-family: Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    color: #595959;
    padding: 0 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.home .trait-box dd span {
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 3px 0;
    margin: 38px auto 40px;
    background: #D06F4A;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-size: 1.07142857rem;
    font-family: 'ProximaNova', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    padding-top: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    opacity: 0;
}

.home .trait-box.main-menu-orange dd span {
    background-color: #D06F4A;
}

.home .trait-box.main-menu-blue dd span {
    background-color: #5E7599;
}

.home .trait-box.main-menu-teal dd span {
    background-color: #405C69;
}

.home .trait-box.main-menu-green dd span {
    background-color: #A9B800;
}

.home .trait-box,
.trait-box figure,
.trait-box dd,
.trait-box dl,
.trait-box dd span {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.22, 0.35, 0.98);
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.22, 0.35, 0.98) 0;
    -o-transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.22, 0.35, 0.98) 0;
    transition: all 300ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.22, 0.35, 0.98) 0;
}

.home .trait-box:hover,
.trait-box.expanded {
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-top: 400px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    background: white;
}

.home .trait-box:hover figure, 
.trait-box.expanded figure {
    height: 184px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dl {
    margin-top: 184px;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dd,
.trait-box.expanded dd { 
    height: 170px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dd span,
.trait-box.expanded dd span {
    opacity: 1;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dd span:hover,
.trait-box.expanded dd span:hover {

}

.home .trait-box:hover,
.trait-box.expanded {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 225ms;
    transition-duration: 225ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.home .trait-box:hover figure, 
.trait-box.expanded figure { 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 225ms;
    transition-duration: 225ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dl, 
.trait-box.expanded dl { 
    -webkit-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 225ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 225ms;
    transition-duration: 225ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 100ms;
    transition-delay: 100ms;
}

.home .trait-box:hover dd,
.trait-box.expanded dd {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 540ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 540ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 540ms;
    transition-duration: 540ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 500ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 500ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 500ms;
    transition-delay: 500ms;
}
.home .trait-box:hover dd span,
.trait-box.expanded dd span {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 540ms;
    -moz-transition-duration: 540ms;
    -o-transition-duration: 540ms;
    transition-duration: 540ms;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 1100ms;
    -moz-transition-delay: 1100ms;
    -o-transition-delay: 1100ms;
    transition-delay: 1100ms;
}
```

Comment: I've run into the little wiggle ("vibrating" as you describe it) before too.  From what I can tell, it is a Chrome-specific bug with CSS3 transitions.  I also think it is specific to animating the opacity property (that is where I encountered it at least).  I never found a fix for it I'm afraid, and although I found other people on Google with this issue, none of them had a solution either.  Probably best to just animate stuff with jQuery instead of CSS3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are causing [browser reflows](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow), which are expensive and change the layout on each animation step, causing the jerkyness and jitterness.

To work around this, you need to apply absolute positioning to your animated elements, adding this to your CSS will get you started:

```
.home .main-navigation ul {
  position: relative;
  height: 180px;
}

.home .main-navigation ul li {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

.home .main-navigation ul li:nth-child(1) { left: 0;}
.home .main-navigation ul li:nth-child(2) { left: 25%;}
.home .main-navigation ul li:nth-child(3) { left: 50%;}
.home .main-navigation ul li:nth-child(4) { left: 75%;}
```

This is just a starting point, you will have to write more CSS in order to correctly display your elements with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I have to say that the menu looks slick. I could use that for a project. What WP theme are you using? It is awesome!

On a serious note, it seems as though the CSS animations are just causing a bug when Chrome renders them. I have two solutions for you (both of them would require some work):

**1.** Use animate.css to see if the prebuilt CSS animations are made better and are stable on Chrome. http://daneden.me/animate/

**2.** Animate the menu with jQuery, which would also be a stable solution.

Comment: It is a custom built theme that i am building for a project. i am trying to make it fully responsive and cross browser compatible and i would rather not overload it with jquery if i don't have to and can do that same with css3

Comment: Your CSS is actually done how it should be, but the wiggle is just a Chrome specific issue, so unfortunately I'm going to have to just say what @ennui said: the only way to do this for Chrome is jQuery. If this is the only jQuery script on your site, it would not be overloading it. Also, for speed, you could a cache plugin like WP Super Cache to make your site fast.