# Background linear gradient transition makes box shake

Tags: css, css-transitions

So this is kind of hard to show, but I will try my best.

Basically I am trying to create a button, or div, that has some corner borders, which then expands on hover, just like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="other-container">
    <div class="corner-box">This is </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
}

.other-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
  display: grid;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.corner-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to right, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to left, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to left, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to top, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  &:hover {
    background:
    linear-gradient(to right, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to right, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to left, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to left, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to top, black 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top, black 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

As such, this actually seems to work when I just run this code. So no problem there. However, when I try to implement it in my project something weird happens.

Basically I am trying to put it in my own code like this (modified of course) in my own code:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="corner-box">This is a test</div>
  <div class="second-div">
     <div class="corner-box">This is a test</div>
  </div>      
</div>
```

My CSS for this looks like this:

```
.content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  padding: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  align-content: start;
  position: relative;
}

.second-div {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-top: 150px;
  align-self: start;
}

.corner-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%;

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;

  &:hover {
    background:
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to right, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to left, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 0,
    linear-gradient(to bottom, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 0,
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 0 100%,
    linear-gradient(to top, teal 2px, transparent 2px) 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    transition: all 1.0s ease-in-out;
  }
}
```

The problem, which I just can't figure out, is that the transition of the `corner-box` div inside the `second-div` looks like this (sorry for the bad gif):

[image]

I hope it shows that the transition/animation makes the right border of the box kind of shaky/wobbly, resulting in a not so pretty effect.

However, the box outside the `second-div` container works as intended, i.e.:

[image]

I honestly have no idea what is happening here. I have tried to strip anything not needed, and it seems that SOMETIMES it might be a positioning issue. So places where I have the box in containers that are center-aligned it sometimes disappear. But like in this case, there really are no positioning at all. Additionally, if I remove the `display: grid` it also seems to disappear in this case, but in other cases (as my example in the beginning) `display: grid` has no effect.
So it's kind of inconclusive. And I just can't remove my `display: grid`, as that is the basis of my entire setup.

So yeah, does anyone might have an answer to why this is happening ?

Comment: Kudos on posting such a well written question. In terms of a solution, it’s difficult to test without a working Fiddle, but could the cause be browser reflows? Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17758386/4604701).